# How can I throw jsonrpc error object with user defined code, message and data from spring boot project

Tags: java, jsonrpc4j

How can I throw jsonrpc error object with user defined code, message and data from spring boot project?
I tried below code, unfortunately passed code and data are not getting inside error. But I am getting passed message.

I have mentioned my code below, I want to get full data object information in error block. please help me on this

RPC request:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "process",
  "params": {
    "request": {
      "origin": "TEST",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  }
}
```

RPC response:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "error": {
        "code": -32001,
        "message": "Invalid request param",
        "data": {
            "exceptionTypeName": "com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcClientException",
            "message": "Invalid request param"
        }
    }
}
```

JAVA Code for throw exception

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        NodeBean data = new NodeBean();
        data.setErrorCode("E400");
        data.setErrorMessage("Test message from error data object");
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.valueToTree(data);
        throw new JsonRpcClientException(1, "Invalid request param", jsonNode);
```

Comment: You have to pass a `JsonNode` object as the third parameter for the `JsonRpcClientException` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had tried by setting JsonNode. But it was not working, please check my code

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: JsonRpc 1.5.3 version does not handle the passed JsonNode object as data. Due to this issue, am not getting the data object in error block. Check the below code in Jar AnnotationsErrorResolver.java
 public JsonError resolveError( 
 return new JsonError(resolver.code(), message, new ErrorData(resolver.exception().getName(), message));